# PHP How can I suppress errors thrown by file_get_contents?

Tags: php

Trying to suppress errors for file_get_contents ONLY but neither of these methods work.. is there another way?

```
$data=@file_get_contents('invalid');

try { $data=@file_get_contents('invalid'); } catch($e Exception) { echo "error"; }
```

Comment: `catch($e Exception)` is incorrect - it should be `catch( Exception $e)`

Comment: You can disable display_errors in php.ini. However, I would suggest checking if whatever you're getting is valid and simply skip the whole process if it's not.

Comment: @RamRaider While you have a point, it's not relevant. `file_get_contents` doesn't throw an exception. It issues a `E_WARNING` which can't be caught as an exception would.

Comment: I don't get any error with `$data=@file_get_contents('invalid');`, without the `@` I do, so it's supressing the error with all error reporting enabled!?

Comment: Use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) instead, which (unlike `file_get_contents`) will *actually* throw exceptions of various useful types.

Comment: If you're reading a local file you could also use `is_readable` first to check a file exists and can be read before trying to open it.

Answer (score 0):

## Fix problems, don't hide them.

Errors, Warnings, and Notices, should be fixed rather hidden ("supressed").

For your case, all you need do is a check for [is_readable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php).

```
function getFile(string $filename = 'invalid')
{
    if (!is_readable($filename)) {
        return false;
    }

    return file_get_contents($filename);
}

$fileContents = getFile('maybevalid');
if (false !== $fileContents) {
    // success
} else {
    // couldn't read
}
```

Comment: I can't fix the availability of other web pages and file_get_contents throws an exception regardless of error handling, but I appreciate your advice. I will give is_readable a shot.

Comment: @Corbin, the point of my example code here, is that you ***can*** fix problems in code _without_ changing the conditions around the code. 

In your case, you know the file may not exist, but `file_get_contents` ***expects*** a filename that _does_ exist (and throws and exception if it does NOT). All that means, is to adjust your code such that `file_get_contents` is NOT passed a file which it cannot read. This is what I mean by "fix the problem," and why I gave the code sample I did.